# MS T-SQL UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Thanks in advance for feedback.

I'm attempting to update a column from conditions in a join.

I can use `SELECT` to return the columns I want, however the `UPDATE` statement does nothing.

I've attempted this two ways (see below). Example two nests the `SELECT` statement which works on its own, returning 12 rows, however when I attempt to update the column, I get either 0 rows returned or 2 rows returned. And the 2 rows aren't the rows in the `SELECT` statement. I'll chase that rabbit down the hole later if need be, but I'd like some feedback on this please.

Query #1:

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE lot_group        
SET lot_group_code = 'Finished'
FROM inv_mast_lot i
LEFT JOIN lot_group l ON i.lot_group_uid = l.lot_group_uid
LEFT JOIN line o  ON i.inv_mast_uid = o.inv_mast_uid
LEFT JOIN header h ON o.order_no = h.order_no
LEFT JOIN inventory m ON i.inv_mast_uid = m.inv_mast_uid
WHERE 
    l.lot_group IS NULL
    AND o.cancel_flag <> 'Y'
    AND o.company_no = 'db1'
    AND o.complete <> 'Y'
    AND o.delete_flag <> 'Y'
    AND h.projected_order <> 'Y'
    AND m.item_id = 'part_1')

ROLLBACK/COMMIT
```

Query #2:

```
BEGIN TRAN      

UPDATE lot_group 
SET lot_group_code = 'Finished'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT l.lot_group_code, m.item_id, l.lot_group_uid   
              FROM inv_mast_lot i
              LEFT JOIN lot_group l ON i.lot_group_uid = l.lot_group_uid
              LEFT JOIN line o ON i.inv_mast_uid = o.inv_mast_uid
              LEFT JOIN header h ON o.order_no = h.order_no
              LEFT JOIN inventory m ON i.inv_mast_uid = m.inv_mast_uid
              WHERE l.lot_group IS NULL
                AND o.cancel_flag <> 'Y'
                AND o.company_no = 'db1'
                AND o.complete <> 'Y'
                AND o.delete_flag <> 'Y'
                AND h.projected_order <> 'Y'
                AND m.item_id = 'part_1') 

ROLLBACK/COMMIT
```

Comment: just to ask the obvious... you're not running the rollback afterwards are you? if not, it's worth removing the transaction stuff from the question as that's not relevant. also, some sample data that allows us to see the problem would help.

Comment: The second UPDATE statement makes little sense, because the subquery has no reference to the table on the outer level (i.e. `UPDATE lot_group`). Just because the table name occurs in both, does not mean they are automatically joined.

Comment: Tanner, the ROLLBACK is there to confirm results only.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble giving any advice here because the queries clearly are not in valid syntax. No data examples and no table structures. So nothing is testable. It's also pretty much debug help, which is off topic.

Comment: What are the results of the select embedded in the first update

Comment: This question needs more [mcve] reworking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would change the update statement to use the alias that is used in the rest of the query. Next to see if the query is returning anything useful, you can embed a commented out select. That way you can run just the select until you are sure you are getting the data that you want to update ensuring the  update with then run correctly. Another technique is to run the select, run the update then run the select rolling back each time until you have the correct results.  I prefer to do the first until I am pretty sure that I am selecting the correct records to update. Then go to the second method to make sure the update happened as I had envisioned.

```
       UPDATE l    
            SET lot_group_code = 'Finished'
--select l.lot_group_code, *
            FROM inv_mast_lot i
            LEFT JOIN lot_group l
                ON i.lot_group_uid = l.lot_group_uid
            LEFT JOIN line o 
                ON i.inv_mast_uid = o.inv_mast_uid
            LEFT JOIN header h
                ON o.order_no = h.order_no
            LEFT JOIN inventory m 
                ON i.inv_mast_uid = m.inv_mast_uid
            WHERE l.lot_group IS NULL
                AND o.cancel_flag <> 'Y'
                AND o.company_no = 'db1'
                AND o.complete <> 'Y'
                AND o.delete_flag <> 'Y'
                AND h.projected_order <> 'Y'
                AND m.item_id = 'part_1')
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but that's exactly what I did.  I use SELECT to confirm the expected results... however I'm at a loss as to why the UPDATE doesn't work.  I tried your suggestion... still 0 results.  I do appreciate your help.

Comment: You do need to fix your where clauses. You are turning all those left joins into inner joins. That could explain why you aren't getting the expected results

Comment: And if fact it makes no sense whatsoever to have the table you are updating be the right side of a left join.  There will be records that are null for all values in that table once you have the joins working correctly. Generally when I write complex update queries, I always start as a baseline with the table I intend to update.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback HLGEM, the LEFT JOINS aren't the issue, they provide the proper results when used with a SELECT and don't make a difference no matter what I do with the JOINS (sometimes you throw logic out the window).  Why does it work if I just use the SELECT statement, then don't when I ask it to UPDATE that field?   I've declared the lot_group table first previously with the same results. I thought the same thing too.

Comment: You don't understand left joins if you say that. There is a difference between left joins and inner joins and converting left joins accidentally to inner ones guarantees that you have incorrect results or you do not need left joins.

Comment: @PuroRock You are not listening.  Yes you have thrown logic out the window.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and kind remarks. 
The issue was in the records in one of the join fields. It was empty. If I misrepresented my knowledge of joins and confused anyone, apologies... but I was going by the suggestions in the questions.  I'm well aware of how joins work.  I appreciate everyone's input.  I'll give everyone the kudos they deserve.  Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

This is just messed up.

There is no purpose to update the target of a left join.
A null means there is nothing there to update.

You negate all the other left joins by putting a condition in the where.